Differential Equation Classes for Arduino-Python Control
I am working with Python and an Arduino. I am trying to implement a control in continuous time, thus I need to create an approximation of the next step using numerical methods. I would like to ask if there is a recommended way to do this.
I am using the following class to update my numerical approximations:
class STA:
"""
Class for the supertwisting algorithm in continuous time
"""
def __init__(self,tau,l1, l2, w1=0.0, w2=0.0):
    self.tau = tau
    self.w1 = [w1]
    self.w2 = [w2]
    self.l1 = l1
    self.l2 = l2

def derivative(self,variable):
    error = self.w1[-1]-variable
    w1_aux = self.tau*(self.w2[-1] - self.l1*(np.sqrt(np.abs(error)))*self.sign(error)) + self.w1[-1]
    w2_aux = self.tau*(-self.l2*self.sign(error)) + self.w2[-1]
    self.w1.append(w1_aux)
    self.w2.append(w2_aux)
    
    return w2_aux

def sign(self, value):
    if value < 0:
        out = -1
    else:
        out = 1
    return out

Basically I am using a Super Twisting Algorithm to approximate the derivative of a signal. I have four parameters and the derivative of the next time is with the function "derivative". I am using the euler approximation to obtain the next step.
I know there are libraries that use numerical methods for solving differential equations. However, as the communication is online, I don't know if this is possible, such as with scipy.ode function.
